# Incorrect string value: '\xAE'

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, odbc, collation

I am trying to write a string with the registered `trademark symbol ®`

This symbol is achieved by pressing Alt then 0174.

When I write the symbol via `MySQL ODBC`, I get the following error report

> Exception occured in Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: [ma-3.1.0][8.0.13]Incorrect string value: '\xAE' for column 'Fast

I have tried changing the charset from latin1 to utf8mb4 and the collation to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` but still got the same error.

I ran the following query too:

```
ALTER TABLE `meddata`.`diabeticglucoseloweringmedications`  
MODIFY COLUMN `FastPumpInsulinName` VARCHAR(30)  
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL;
```

How can I write ® to a MySQL database?

Comment: You sure you connect with the utf8mb4 charset also?

Answer (score 1):

Hex `AE` is the latin1 (and cp1250, cp1251, cp1256, cp1257, geostd8, hebrew, latin5, latin7) encoding for `®`.

It is OK to use latin1, but someone in the path is expecting UTF-8, hence the problem.

It would be 'better' to use UTF-8 everywhere.  Where did you press that ALT sequence?  If it is the `cmd` tool in Windows, then

> The command "chcp" controls the "code page". chcp 65001 provides utf8, but it needs a special charset installed, too. some code pages
>   To set the font in the console window: Right-click on the title of the window → Properties → Font → pick Lucida Console

-- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#entering_accents_in_cmd

Comment: I set the character set to utf8mb4  as per the script.

Comment: @SeanJ I am suggesting that the _client_ is at fault.